# How to detect speed using android mobine

Tags: android

I want to detect the speed of vehicle when I drive with the android device. How can I write it ?

Comment: You need to provide context to your question, StackOverflow isn't google!

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Find out how to use LocationManager and LocationListener - [start here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html). When listener gives you the result Location, you can find out the speed with [getSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Its only start.Many more to do.
`Vehicle measurements are accessed through an Android service. Your application connects to an in-process VehicleService which handles reading fresh data from the vehicle.`
For details see the link.
http://openxcplatform.com/developers/android/library-usage.html